# No java executable found

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

I am getting the following notification in my vs code while working in my flutter project:

No java executable found, please consider to configure your 'java,jdt.Is.java.home' setting or set JAVA_HOME in your path or put a Java executable in your path.

source :Gradle for java (extention)

I have seen this notification for a few times since installing "gradle for java" extention, not sure what it means.

Comment: Use JarFix: https://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Java JDK 11

   [Download Link For JDK 11](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5553-java-jdk.html)
2. set environment variables Like this

   [image]
3. Than Restart your PC/Laptop

Comment: Why Java JDK 11? From the JDK website "JDK 20 is the latest release of Java SE Platform and JDK 17 LTS is the latest long-term support release for the Java SE platform."